# Filter not working for searchbar UITextField in tableView Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I have implemented searchbar(UITextField) for tableView and defined same array of `SectionList` but exactly no idea filtering is not working. when I try to print `IndexData` it has data but `tableFilterData` is empty.

> This is the main line which shows empty. 
>   `tableFilterdata =  IndexData.filter({$0.names.contains(searchText) })`

```
var IndexData = [SectionList]()`

var tableFilterdata = [SectionList]()`

var isSearch : Bool! = false`


struct SectionList {
        let letter : String
        let names : [String]
    }
```

Main Functions

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       searchTxt.resignFirstResponder()
       return true
    }

public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

        let searchText  = searchTxt.text! + string

        print(IndexData)

        tableFilterdata =  IndexData.filter({$0.names.contains(searchText) })

        print(tableFilterdata)
        if(tableFilterdata.count == 0){
           isSearch = false
         }else{
           isSearch = true
        }


        tableView.reloadData()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: What is the result of `print(IndexData)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace,

```
let searchText  = searchTxt.text! + string

        print(IndexData)

        tableFilterdata =  IndexData.filter({$0.names.contains(searchText.lowercased()) })
```

with

```
if string.isEmpty {
    searchText = String(searchText.dropLast())
}
else {
    searchText = textField.text!+string
}

print(IndexData)

self.IndexData.removeAll()
self.tableFilterdata.removeAll()
if searchText.count == 0 {
    self.tableFilterdata = self.IndexData
} else {
    tableFilterdata =  IndexData.filter{ ($0.names.contains(searchText)) }
}
```

Comment: its giving error on two places.

1) `String(search.dropLast())` search dropLast whats that ?

2) Last line `IndexData` -- `Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored`

Comment: `Value of type '[String]' has no member 'localizedCaseInsensitiveContains'` on `IndexData.filter`

Comment: I set it to `IndexData.filter{ ($0.letter.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))} ` but after that number of Rows in Section gives this error `tableFilterdata[section].names.count  --  index out of range`

Comment: You used `letter` in filter and you trying to get count from names?

Comment: I have set it all but search available only with `letter` not with `names` because `names : [String]`  and is not working on `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains` In this scenario what can I do that it search with names.

Comment: You can also use `contains` for names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206850/discussion-between-niraj-ios-and-newbie-mobile).

Comment: Yes I tried with that `contains` but only names starting with alphabet `I` works but very slow. other ones not comes in search list

Comment: you deleted previous question ... ?